# How to get Swagger UI's key to be Dropdown menu instead of Text Input

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger to display my RESTful API, one parameter of an API takes string as input and convert it to enum value. Is there any way to display get Swagger UI's key to be Dropdown menu instead of Text Input.

Comment: @spandey15 I'm working on Nodejs. please post swagger file.

Comment: @ Vinod Kumar Marupu  Sorry no idea on node js.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting full example here.swagger 2 configuration you can do from here http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

### Application.java

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

### QuestionCategory.java

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public enum QuestionCategory {
    CSE("cse"),ECE("ece");

    private String value;

    private QuestionCategory(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static QuestionCategory fromValue(String value) {
        for (QuestionCategory category : values()) {
            if (category.value.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return category;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Unknown enum type " + value + ", Allowed values are " + Arrays.toString(values()));
    }

}
```

### Question.java

```java
public class Question {
    private QuestionCategory type;
    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public QuestionCategory getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(QuestionCategory type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
```

### QuestionController.java

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.devglan.model.Question;
import com.devglan.model.QuestionCategory;
import com.devglan.model.QuestionCategoryConverter;

@RestController
public class QuestionController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List get(@PathVariable(value = "type") QuestionCategory category) {
        return getQuestionsByCategory(category);
    }

    private List getQuestionsByCategory(QuestionCategory category) {
        List questions = new ArrayList();
        Question question = new Question();
        question.setType(category);

        if (category == QuestionCategory.CSE) {
            question.setQuestion("What is Operating System.");
            question.setAnswer("This is the answer of what is os.");
        } else if (category == QuestionCategory.ECE) {
            question.setQuestion("What is a transistor.");
            question.setAnswer("This is the answer of what is transistor.");
        }

        questions.add(question);
        return questions;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder webdataBinder) {
        webdataBinder.registerCustomEditor(QuestionCategory.class, new QuestionCategoryConverter());
    }
}
```

### QuestionCategoryConverter.java

```java
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;

public class QuestionCategoryConverter extends PropertyEditorSupport{

    public void setAsText(final String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        setValue(QuestionCategory.fromValue(text));
    }
}
```